# Exclude matched string python re.findall

Tags: python, regex, string, text-processing

I am using python's re.findall method to find occurrence of certain string value in Input string.
e.g. From search in 'ABCdef' string, I have two search requirements.

1. Find string starting from Single Capital letter.
2. After 1 find string that contains all capital letter.

e.g. input string and expected output will be:

- `'USA' --          output: ['USA']`
- `'BObama' --          output: ['B', 'Obama']`
- `'Institute20CSE' --          output: ['Institute', '20', 'CSE']`

So My expectation from

```
>>> matched_value_list = re.findall ( '[A-Z][a-z]+|[A-Z]+' , 'ABCdef' )
```

is to return `['AB', 'Cdef']`.

But which does Not seems to be happening. What I get is `['ABC']` as return value, which matches later part of regex with full string.

So Is there any way we can ignore found matches. So that once `'Cdef'` is matched with `'[A-Z][a-z]+'`. second part of regex (i.e. `'[A-Z]+'`) only matches with remaining string `'AB'`?

Comment: your question is `unclear`..and why do you need to do that..

Comment: Can you detail what you would expect if your string was ``'CdefAB'``

Comment: @sotapme: It should be ['Cdef' , 'AB'].

Comment: That's what I suspected, the good answers below don't deal with that case. I suggest you change your question to reflect that requirement. Likewise is it only for a pair of words ? What would you expect for 'ABXYZCdefXYZAbc' and 'MumABXYZCdefXYZAbc'

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ: I have few strings. Each of which contains few words without space separation (But each word starts with either Capital letter or number or it can be group of capital letters). I am trying to divide them into list of words by detecting where to separate. e.g. strings 'ANiceRoad', 'USA', 'BObama', 'Institute20CSE' etc.

Comment: I was using their original versions #1 which did not. That's why I sought clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need to match `AB`, which is followed by an Uppercase alphabet and then a lowercase alphabet. or is at the end of the string. For that you can use `look-ahead`.

Then you need to match an Uppercase alphabet `C`, followed by multiple lowercase alphabets `def`.

So, you can use this pattern:

```
>>> s = "ABCdef"
>>> re.findall("([A-Z]+(?=[A-Z][a-z]|$)|[A-Z][a-z]+)", s)
['AB', 'Cdef']

>>> re.findall("([A-Z]+(?=[A-Z][a-z]|$)|[A-Z][a-z]+)", 'MumABXYZCdefXYZAbc')
['Mum', 'ABXYZ', 'Cdef', 'XYZ', 'Abc']
```

---

As pointed out in comment by @sotapme, you can also modify the above regex to: -

```
"([A-Z]+(?=[A-Z]|$)|[A-Z][a-z]+|\d+)"
```

Added `\d+` since you also want to match digit as in one of your example. Also, he removed `[a-z]` part from the first part of look-ahead. That works because, `+` quantifier on the `[A-Z]` outside is greedy by default, so, it will automatically match maximum string, and will stop only before the last `upper case` alphabet.

Comment: Hi Rohit, Thanks alot for reply. But above solution might NOT work in case string is 'CdefAB' as mentioned by @sotapme above. In that case I won't get 'AB' in response list. But it will be ['Cdef']. Is there any way to make it such that It ignore already matched strings and work on rest?

Comment: @lalit. Yeah updated the answer. Just add one `$` in the first part of regex.

Comment: I found during my tests of trying to understand your solution that ``"([A-Z]+(?=[A-Z]|$)|[A-Z][a-z]+)"`` worked ie. removed middle ``[a-z]``

Comment: @sotapme. Yeah you are right. I overlooked that part. Since `+` quantifier is greedy by default, it will automatically match maximum possible string as possible. Nice catch :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex

```
[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*?(?=[A-Z][a-z]|[^a-zA-Z]|$)
```